# extend an existing struct/class to serialize it into a string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
//vector.h
        struct Vector
    {
        public:
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    }
```

I have this library which provides me with certain classes and their methods.
How do I extend these classes in my own application code?

right now I am `memcopy` this vector into a char array and then udp sending it, and then udp receive on the other side and then memcopy ing it into a vector instance from a  char array with `3*sizeof(double)`.

How do I extend the struct or similar classes so that I can simply

```
std::string<<vector;
```

and then send this string to my udp send

and udp receive and then copy the received message directly into a vector?

Comment: Check the [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need/want an overload of `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Vector const &v){ 
   return os << v.x << "\t" << v.y << "\t" << v.z;
}
```

Note that instead of writing directly to a string, you'll use this to write to an `std::ostringstream` (but it's trivial to get an `std::string` of the contents of a `stringstream`.

For reading, you do pretty much the same thing with `operator>>`:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Vector &v) { 
    return is >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
}
```

Note that when you write, this does not automatically insert delimiters between the `Vector` objects. Typically you'll want to insert something like`\n` between one Vector and the next.

Also note that this stores the data in text format. Depending on your situation, you may prefer binary -- it's generally more compact and faster to read and write (but also more fragile, so seemingly minor corruption can destroy an entire file).

Oh -- one other detail. In case it wasn't clear, these functions should *not* be members of your `Vector` class, but if you put `Vector` into namespace, you want to keep these functions in the same namespace with it.

Comment: thanks, and how do I do it the other way round, from string message to copy to vector?

Comment: @user494461 Overload the input operator, `operator>>`.

Comment: thanks for the extra decription! cheers

Comment: How do I use binary format to store data in ostream?

Comment: @user494461: You'd usually use something like: `your_stream.write((void *)&variable, sizeof(variable));`